# Xcode 9 Server exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}

Tags: ios, icloud, xcodebuild, xcode9, xcode-server

I upgraded to Xcode 9 Server recently and discovered a sudden problem. There were several other problems i had until i came to this error. I changed from automatic signing to manual singing back and forth. Now in my iOS project i've set it manually and on the server i tried both. The build is successful and it produces an archive (i can't download it though), but it also gives me the error:

`exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided`

I also checked the integration output directory and it doesn't produce a ipa file.

Since i don't trigger the xcodebuild manually i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could only get it to work by providing a custom exportOptionsPlist file in the Bot's config tab. But in my opinion that should not be necessary...

[image]

[image]