# Xcode Error - Profile doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, archive, ios-provisioning

We have enabled iCloud capability in our application and enabled below services,

1. Key-value storage
2. iCloud Documents

But while trying to export the build through the archive, it's throwing me the below error,

> Profile doesn't include the `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` entitlement.

I have tried to set the `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment entitlement` in Entitlements file also as `Production` or `Development` but it did not help me either.

Any clue how to resolve this error?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Why haven’t you checked any containers?

Comment: I tried that as well but while doing that it shows that no containers are configured for the profile

Comment: Yes but what if you make one. You see they used to make one for you. Now you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I tried this but getting the below error, `provisioning profile doesn't support icloud container`

Comment: If anyone here has this problem and automatic signing isn't working - check if your account have enough permissions on the project. This may be the case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

1. I created an iCloud container on the CloudKit dashboard (in the iCloud section of the Signing & Capabilities in Xcode).
2. I assigned the newly created container to my app ([Developer Website > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) > my app ID > Capabilities > iCloud > Edit button) and saved the app ID configuration.
3. Then I created a new App Store provisioning profile for this app ID and used it to manually sign the app when I uploaded it in Xcode.

Comment: Great, thanks !! it worked for me. Now while exporting the archive file its throwing me the below error `Error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to fix that. I don't really understand any of this stuff, I just poke around and try things until something works. There's an answered SO question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423169/xcode-9-server-exportarchive-exportoptionsplist-error-for-key-icloudcontainere so you can maybe try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it helped I just had to add `iCloudContainerEnvironment ` key in my export.plist file as the value`Development `

Comment: I had permissions problems so I asked other guy to do the step 2. So if anyone here has this problem and automatic signing isn't working - check if your account have enough permissions on the project.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be done by Automatically manage signing. Just select the team, add Capability ICloud. Mark Tick on Container Checkbox and you will get the container there.
Reference screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: I feel like this needs more info

Comment: I made it the reverse-domain appId I already had. Seems to be the recommendation. but why is it red? the icloud container is red in xcode. App builds and distributes now, I think so I wonder

Answer (score 5):

I followed this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651070). Look at the answer from @AppleStaff that says to click this [link](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/cloudContainer/add/)

Here is a screenshot of it filled out:

[image]

In the `Description` section you can add whatever you. At the bottom of the`Identifier` section, it says

> We recommend using a reverse-domain name style string (i.e.,
> com.domainname.appname).

Fill it out like this-

`Identifier`: *iCloud.com.yourCompanyName.yourAppName*

`Description`: *yourAppNameContainer* (or whatever you want)

Press **Continue** when your finished.

Afterwards, go to `Xcode` > `Blue icon` in the upper left hand corner > `Signing & Capabilities` (in the `Targets` section) > `iCloud` (you should have already previously enabled iCloud) > click the small `Reload Button` (wait a few seconds) > `tick` the name that you choose above:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For me, the trick was making sure it was capitalized: "Production" is different from "production" according to Apple.

As indicated:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_icloud-container-environment

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer will help you.

-> Goto your Certificate entitlement and open the source code and put there

```
<key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudDocuments</string>
        <string>CloudKit</string>
    </array>
 <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
    <string>Production</string>
```

**You can look the screenshot below**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps, which might help you

- Go to the [apple dev portal](https://developer.apple.com)
- open **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** section
- edit/create your existing provisioning profile manually
- download it from the portal, name it uniquely so you can distinguish
  it from the Xcode generated, i.e. **"MyNewProfile"**
- export the archive and assign **MyProfile**